# Ошибка: module object is not callable

Tags: python, disnake

Код:

```py
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands


bot = commands.bot(command_prefix="*", intents=disnake.Intents.all())
```

ошибка в `bot commands` не пойму из-за чего.

Answer (score 0):

Вот исправленный вариант:

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands

intents = disnake.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*", intents=intents)
```

Ошибка возникла из-за того, что вы написали "bot" вместо "Bot". Также я бы рекомендовал передавать в функцию именно переменную, а не другую функцию, как показано в примере.